# Message Carbon Issue in Openfire 3.9.3 -Not getting carbon messages in all logged in devices

Tags: jquery, xmpp, server, openfire, strophe

I am using  **openfire(3.9.3)**  with  **strophe.js**  I want to implement message carbon feature to support multidevice login .

I have followed http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html but when I fetch all features that time it does not show any carbon related feature and when I try to enable carbon, it return **iq** as shown in the link denots carbon has been enabled .

Now problem is when I login from multiple pc with same userA(but different resources) and send message from **pidgin**(with same userA) to another userB then only one userA among other pc's gets carbon message not all get carbon message.
Even in **openfire settings**  '*route.all-resources*'  property is true.

what exactly has gone wrong over here?

Comment: What is the feature you use in Strophe to try to achieve the message Carbon??

Answer (score 1):

It should work if all your resources have the same priority but Pidgin seems to have issues [setting this option](https://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/1345) in the latest version too (2.10.11).

Comment: I am just wondering what is the feature do i supposed to use in Strophe to try to achieve the message Carbon??

Comment: You need to send an IQ.
From [http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0280.html):  
When a client wants to participate in the Carbons protocol, it enables the protocol by sending an IQ-set containing a child element <enable/> qualified by the namespace "urn:xmpp:carbons:2":  

`<iq xmlns='jabber:client'
    from='romeo@montague.example/garden'
    id='enable1'
    type='set'>
  <enable xmlns='urn:xmpp:carbons:2'/>
</iq>`